# Does a cross-section of the Red Dwarf ship exist?

Tags: red-dwarf

There are cross section for other space ships available, often in art books or similar media.

The best I could find was a schematic from the fandom wiki:

[image: A red line schematic/blueprint of the red dwarf ship, showing unlabelled technical bits in the primary hull, as well as the drive systems, a red and yellow channel through the center, connecting to a ramscoop collector]

But it fails to give details on the levels or floor plans of the ship.

Comment: That schematic seems to be based on concept art created for Season 7; https://www.reddwarf.co.uk/news/2007/08/31/a-thousand-words/dvd_a_thousand_words_310807_2.jpg

Comment: If there is one, probably some Smeghead borrowed it

Answer (score 3):

Actor Dan Barker (who appeared as a voiceover actor in various episodes of the show) was given description of the layout of decks 1 and 2 as part of his studio orientation. He shared that with his fans.

[image]

---

A schematic of Deck C was used as a background prop in season X

[image]

---

In the 1996 "[Red Dwarf Log Book](https://reddwarf.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Dwarf_1996_Log_Book)", Rimmer proposed that the ship be internally remodelled thusly;

[image]

The Cat offered a similar set of suggestions (tent not to scale, presumably).

[image]

Comment: And yes, I do appreciate that this is only a tiny part of a 5 mile long ship, but beggars can't be choosers.